# getting windows-8 spelling corrector to work with all applications

Tags: windows-8, autocorrect

IE 10 can make use of the windows-8's default auto spelling corrector feature [when it is enabled].

Now, **How to make chrome, notepad etc. to make use of auto spelling corrector feature of windows 8?**

Comment: Chrome has it's own spell checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot enable support yourself.  This has to be implemented by the author of a given program.

So this means Microsoft has to make Notepad worked with this feature and likewise Google enable it to work with Chrome ( unlikely since it already has its own spell checker using Google's online dictionary ).

Comment: Thought so earlier.